# In pandas, how to create a new dataframe from the proportions of another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

In python3 and pandas I have this dataframe:

```
df_total.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 388950 entries, 0 to 12533
Data columns (total 22 columns):
 #   Column                                Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------                                --------------   ----- 
 0   IdPedido                              388950 non-null  object
 1   ProtocoloPedido                       388950 non-null  object
 2   OrgaoDestinatario                     388950 non-null  object
 3   Situacao                              388950 non-null  object
 4   DataRegistro                          388950 non-null  object
 5   ResumoSolicitacao                     388950 non-null  object
 6   DetalhamentoSolicitacao               388950 non-null  object
 7   PrazoAtendimento                      388950 non-null  object
 8   FoiProrrogado                         388950 non-null  object
 9   FoiReencaminhado                      388950 non-null  object
 10  FormaResposta                         388950 non-null  object
 11  OrigemSolicitacao                     388950 non-null  object
 12  IdSolicitante                         388950 non-null  object
 13  CategoriaPedido                       388950 non-null  object
 14  SubCategoriaPedido                    388950 non-null  object
 15  NumeroPerguntas                       388950 non-null  object
 16  DataResposta                          388950 non-null  object
 17  Resposta                              388950 non-null  object
 18  TipoResposta                          388950 non-null  object
 19  ClassificacaoTipoResposta             388950 non-null  object
 20  OrgaoSuperiorAssociadoaoDestinatario  205394 non-null  object
 21  id_ano                                388950 non-null  object
dtypes: object(22)
memory usage: 68.3+ MB
```

It is a dataframe on requests for access to information in Brazil. The “OrgaoDestinatario” column has the name of the institutions that received the requests. And the column "TipoResposta" which was the type of response to the request

I counted the two columns

```
df_total['OrgaoDestinatario'].value_counts()
ME - Ministério da Economia                                                  42559
MS – Ministério da Saúde                                                     17196
ANEEL – Agência Nacional de Energia Elétrica                                 12996
INSS – Instituto Nacional do Seguro Social                                   11059
MAPA – Ministério da Agricultura, Pecuária e Abastecimento                   10215
                                                                             ...  
EBSERH - HUJB-UFCG - Hospital Universitário Júlio Maria Bandeira de Mello       38
EBSERH - HUAP-UFF - Hospital Universitário Antônio Pedro                        23
EBSERH - HUAC-UFCG - Hospital Universitário Alcides Carneiro                    17
EBSERH - HC-UFPE - Hospital das Clínicas de Pernambuco                          14
EBSERH - HC-UFU - Hospital de Clínicas de Uberlândia                             7
Name: OrgaoDestinatario, Length: 305, dtype: int64

df_total['TipoResposta'].value_counts()
Acesso Concedido                                            278712
Acesso Negado                                                25187
Não se trata de solicitação de informação                    23719
Acesso Parcialmente Concedido                                18365
Informação Inexistente                                       13794
Órgão não tem competência para responder sobre o assunto     13233
Pergunta Duplicada/Repetida                                   8677
Encaminhado para o e-Ouv                                      7263
Name: TipoResposta, dtype: int64
```

And also sub-counts within an “TipoResposta” of an entity. Example:

```
eco = df_total[(df_total['OrgaoDestinatario'] == 'ME - Ministério da Economia')]
eco['TipoResposta'].value_counts()
Acesso Concedido                                            22928
Não se trata de solicitação de informação                    7887
Acesso Negado                                                4070
Encaminhado para o e-Ouv                                     3115
Órgão não tem competência para responder sobre o assunto     1291
Pergunta Duplicada/Repetida                                  1134
Informação Inexistente                                       1124
Acesso Parcialmente Concedido                                1010
Name: TipoResposta, dtype: int64
```

I want to create a new dataframe in which there is a column called “list_of_entities” and each line of it contains “OrgaoDestinatario” information, without repeating it (in this case 305 lines). Example:

```
list_of_entities
ME - Ministério da Economia
CEF – Caixa Econômica Federal
MS – Ministério da Saúde
ANEEL – Agência Nacional de Energia Elétrica
INSS – Instituto Nacional do Seguro Social
BACEN – Banco Central do Brasil
MAPA – Ministério da Agricultura, Pecuária e Abastecimento
…
```

And the other columns with the names found in "TipoResposta": “Acesso Concedido”, “ Não se trata de solicitação de informação”, “Acesso Negado”…

But the rows in each of these columns will have the result of math account, a number, relative to the value of "list_of_entities": the sum of the “TipoResposta” category of the respective entity divided by the total requests of that entity, multiplied by 100 Example:

“ME - Ministério da Economia” had 42,559 requests and in the item “Acesso Concedido” there were 22,928 cases. So it's 22,928 / 42,559 * 100 = 53.87 So in the new dataframe in the line “ME - Ministério da Economia” and in the column “Acesso Concedido” there would be the value 53,87

And the same type of account for the other "TipoResposta" columns. And in the next line, with the other types of "OrgaoDestinatario", repeat the same type of account in the columns

Please, does anyone know how I could do this with Python?

---/---

February 27 edition

With these steps I was able to generate a dataframe with the information I need

```
# First I made a value_counts for the items of 'OrgaoDestinatario', saved it as a dataframe and renamed the columns
conta_orgao = df_total['OrgaoDestinatario'].value_counts().reset_index()
conta_orgao.rename(columns={"index": "nome_orgao"}, inplace=True)
conta_orgao.rename(columns={"OrgaoDestinatario": "conta_vez"}, inplace=True)
conta_orgao.reset_index().head()
index   nome_orgao  conta_vez
0   0   ME - Ministério da Economia     42559
1   1   MS – Ministério da Saúde    17196
2   2   ANEEL – Agência Nacional de Energia Elétrica    12996
3   3   INSS – Instituto Nacional do Seguro Social  11059
4   4   MAPA – Ministério da Agricultura, Pecuária e A...   10215

# Then a groupby with two columns ('OrgaoDestinatario','TipoResposta') and with size, and renamed the column with the count, and saved it as a dataframe
conta_tipo = df_total.groupby(['OrgaoDestinatario','TipoResposta']).size().reset_index()
conta_tipo.rename(columns={0: "conta_por_orgao"}, inplace=True)
conta_tipo.reset_index().head()
    index   OrgaoDestinatario   TipoResposta    conta_por_orgao
0   0   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Acesso Concedido    153
1   1   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Acesso Negado   25
2   2   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Acesso Parcialmente Concedido   23
3   3   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Informação Inexistente  40
4   4   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Não se trata de solicitação de informação   143

# I made a copy of this dataframe with another name to group the final results afterwards
contagem_geral = conta_tipo.copy()


# This function reads all the lines of the copied dataframe above
# And create a new column
# First I load the name of each 'OrgaoDestinatario' in the variable "orgao"
# Then the size value of the groupby of 'OrgaoDestinatario' and 'TipoResposta' in the "conta_por_orgao" variable
# And then iterate on the other dataframe with the total number of items in each 'OrgaoDestinatario'
# And I load in a variable the 'OrgaoDestinatario' of this iteration and put it in "orgao_vez"
# And I load the value_counts of 'OrgaoDestinatario', in "total"
# If "orgao" and "orgao_vez" I count the proportion
# And I send this value to be placed in the new column that I had created on the dataframe copies
# And it continues on all lines

def limpeza(linha):
    orgao = linha["OrgaoDestinatario"]
    conta_por_orgao = linha["conta_por_orgao"]

    for num, row in conta_orgao.iterrows():
        orgao_vez = row['nome_orgao']
        total = row['conta_vez']

        if orgao == orgao_vez:
            valor = int(conta_por_orgao) / int(total) * 100
            valor = float(valor)
            return valor

contagem_geral["proporcao_em_relacao_ao_total_do_orgao"] = contagem_geral.apply(limpeza, axis=1)

contagem_geral.reset_index().head()
    index   OrgaoDestinatario   TipoResposta    conta_por_orgao     proporcao_em_relacao_ao_total_do_orgao
0   0   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Acesso Concedido    153     28.544776
1   1   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Acesso Negado   25  4.664179
2   2   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Acesso Parcialmente Concedido   23  4.291045
3   3   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Informação Inexistente  40  7.462687
4   4   ABGF - Agencia Brasileira Gestora de Fundos Ga...   Não se trata de solicitação de informação   143     26.679104
```

Comment: You want some sort of `groupby('list_of_entities').mean()`

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang I edited above and put a solution that worked for me, it is not very elegant but it worked